# Windows Explorer cuts off folder names after dot (.)

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

For some reason, Windows Explorer has started cutting off everything after a dot (.) in my folder names.

Example:

[image]

Any ideas?  I do have TortoiseSVN installed, which provides the icon overlays, but that's never been an issue before.

Also, I'm using Windows 7 64-bit and *Hide Extensions for know filetypes* is **not checked**.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the 'feature' to hide extensions. Check in the Folder-Options (you can find it in the Control Panel, and then the tabpage View) for it.

**Edit:** Oh, in that case sorry, [this](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7files/thread/314f2442-8d70-4d19-a658-4cbba25d783b) is the only discussion which I found whcih comes close to your problem.

Comment: This is -supposed- to just be for files, but it's the first thing that I thought of too. If it IS infact a solution, there must still be a deeper problem.

Comment: That's the first thing I checked.  **Hide extensions for known file types** is **unchecked**.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so following the link that Bobby posted, I found the solution.  I had originally changed the default folder that the Windows Explorer taskbar icon opened to.  So, instead of opening to:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe
```

I modified it to open directly into my C Drive:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe /n, /e, /select, C:\
```

After noticing that the folders *were* correctly named if I opened Computer from the start menu and navigated to the same directories, I changed the shortcut back to the original string and that seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I have not changed the link of my taskbar icon. I do have TortoiseSVN installed.

Answer (score 2):

I found [a solution posted by Lee Diggins](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/truncated-folder-names-extension-missing/596fb09b-c41d-42e8-9d14-95a02352d554?tab=question&status=AllReplies&status=AllReplies,AllReplies,AllReplies) at Microsoft Community that fixes the problem. It is a [Fix it tool from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_file_and_folder_diag/).

One thing to note is that if you have some customisations you wish to remain, for example customs icon for files/folder, be sure to choose the option of **Detect problems and let me choose the fixes to apply** instead so that you can choose which fixes are desired.

For me I only chose the fix for View and Customisation problem for a folder.

Answer (score 0):

This corrected the problem for me.

I had changed the explorer target to open on *My Computer* with following argument:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
```

Restoring the target to `%windir%\explorer.exe` corrects the problem, without having to restart windows. And after having launched Explorer at least once, I can reset the target to the modified path.

Answer (score 0):

For myself, I saw this when starting Explorer from the link pinned to my task bar. If I opened Explorer from the start menu or the "This PC" link on my desktop it worked fine.

I fixed the problem by unpinning Explorer from the task bar, opening a new Explorer window, navigating to my desired folder, and pinning again.

I don't know what originally triggered the problem (it had previously been okay) so I don't know if this solution will be permanent. The problem may have been related to Tortoise SVN (as the original question suggested), as I recently installed that, but none of the solutions offered here fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I've posted basically this same answer at https://superuser.com/questions/1083173, not sure if that is a breach of etiquette or good practice.