# Windows 10 Explorer cuts off folder name after last period character

Tags: windows-10

I recently upgraded my PC to Windows 10 and all was fine for the first few days, but now all of the sudden Windows Explorer does not show complete folder names which contain period characters.  All characters past the last period are removed.  If I right click on the folder and select "Properties", the entire name shows up.  I have searched this topic on Google and found several references to a Microsoft Fix-It that can be run which supposedly fixes this problem, but it is not compatible with Windows 10.

Here is an image of what I see:
[image]

The only thing I can think of that may have triggered this is I installed a new version of Tortoise SVN.  Not sure if this had anything to do with it or not.  I also verified that the option "Hide extensions for known files types" is NOT enabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's just display issue. No worry about Tortoise SVN. Just browse files in something better than explorer... e.g. TotalCommander.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: See if resetting folder views helps. In File Explorer > View tab > Options > View tab > Reset folders.

Comment: It may be TortoiseSVN: Pls check same/similar issue here. http://superuser.com/questions/112577/windows-explorer-cuts-off-folder-names-after-dot

And in that case Reset folders should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For myself, I saw this when starting Explorer from the link pinned to my task bar. If I opened Explorer from the start menu or the "This PC" link on my desktop it worked fine.

I fixed the problem by unpinning Explorer from the task bar, opening a new Explorer window, navigating to my desired folder, and pinning again.

I don't know what originally triggered the problem (it had previously been okay) so I don't know if this solution will be permanent. The problem may have been related to Tortoise SVN (as some of the comments on the original question note), as I recently installed that, but none of the solutions offered at [Windows Explorer cuts off folder names after dot (.)](https://superuser.com/questions/112577) fixed the problem for me.